# MapFish:print Styling not applying

Tags: mapfish

I'm trying to build a MapFish Style that i can apply to mixed Well known text types

example feature

```
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [...],
  "properties": {
    "Name": "KN",
    "id": "5a002a8e9ee4e84a3c125067",
    "geoType": "LineString",
    ...
  },
  "profile":{...}
  "type": "Feature"
},
```

and i am applying this style

```
{
    "version": "2",
    "[geoType IN ('LineString', 'MultiLineString', 'Curve', 'MultiCurve', 'CompoundCurve')]": {
        "symbolizers": [{
            "type": "Line",
            "strokeColor": "#000080",
            "strokeOpacity": "0.65",
            "strokeWidth": "5.0"
        }]
    },
    "[geoType IN ('Polygon', 'MultiPolygon', 'Triangle', 'CircularString', 'CurvePolygon')]": {
        "symbolizers": [{
            "type": "Line",
            "strokeColor": "#000080",
            "strokeOpacity": "0.65",
            "strokeWidth": "5.0"
        }, {
            "type": "polygon",
            "strokeColor": "#000080",
            "strokeOpacity": "0.65",
            "strokeWidth": "5.0",
            "fillColor": "#000080",
            "fillOpacity": "0.65"
        }]
    },
    "[geoType IN ('Point', 'MultiPoint')]": {
        "symbolizers": [{
            "type": "point",
            "pointRadius": "20",
            "graphicName": "circle",
            "graphicWidth": "20",
            "strokeColor": "#000080",
            "strokeOpacity": "0.65",
            "strokeWidth": "5.0",
            "fillColor": "#000080",
            "fillOpacity": "0.65"
        }]
    }
}
```

it is throwing no error and the print completed but when i get nothing from the GeoJSON

any pointers on what I've got wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the Profile attribute, not sure why but if your GeoJson has any extra properties in the root of the node mapfish wont process it